# Pegar id e nome via form, ambos forenig key

Tags: django, django-2.0

Basicamente o usuario entra no perfil da empresa e faz um comentario e uma avaliação de nota.
Preciso que nesse form sejam passados o ID da empresa e pego o ID ou o Nome do Usuario
Tenho um sistema que usa USER extendidos para Usuario e Negocio.
E criei uma tabela Comentario, que importa o Id do User da tabela Negocio e o Nome da tabela usuario.
Mais não estou conseguindo passar via view a id da empresa nem o nome do usuario que está comentando.
Lembrando que só usuarios cadastrados poderão comentar

models.py

```
class Negocio(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Usuario(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Comentario(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    nota = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=NOTA_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def comentario_form(request):
    comentario = Comentario.objects.all()
    form = ComentarioForm()
    data = {'comentario': comentario, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile_negocio/comentario.html', data)

def cadastro_comentario(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComentarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.nome = request.user
            user.usuario.nome = form.cleaned_data.get('comentario')
            user.usuario.sobrenome = form.cleaned_data.get('nota')
            user.save()

            return redirect('sistema_perfil')
    else:
        form = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'profile_negocio/comentario.html', {'form': form})
```

comentario.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'cadastro_comentario' %}" 
    class="form-signin" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form" validate>
      {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row ">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-center">
          {{ form.comentario| as_crispy_field}}
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-center">
              {{ form.nota| as_crispy_field}}
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
```

profile.html

```
{% for comentario in comentarios %}
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ comentario.nome }} - Nota: {{ comentario.nota }} 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ comentario.comentario }}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a pergunta, algum problema em alguma parte do codigo? Em que parte do codigo vc precisa de ajuda?

Comment: Na view, preciso que passe automaticamente para o ofrmulario a id do Negócio, que é a página onde o usuário vai comentar e passar tbm o nome do usuário que está comentando

Comment: Vou melhorar a formatcao para ver se fica mais claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, dei uma refatorada no código usando CBV, tenta ai:

```
#models.py
class Negocio(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Usuario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Comentario(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Negocio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    nota = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=NOTA_CHOICES, blank=True)

#forms.py
from django import forms

class ComentarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comentario
        fields = '__all__'

#views.py
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class ComentarioFormView(generic.UpdateView):

    model = Comentario
    form_class = ComentarioForm
    template_name = 'profile_negocio/comentario.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name_da_url_para_direcionar_em_caso_de_sucesso_s2')

    def Negocio(self):
        return Negocio.objects.all()


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = form
        comentario = Comentario(
                user=self.request.user.username,
                nome=form.cleaned_data.get('nome'),
                empresa=form.cleaned_data.get('empresa'),
                comentario=form.cleaned_data.get('comentario'),
                nota=form.cleaned_data.get('nota'),
            )
        comentario.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```